# Calculate Line Number in Log with Logstash Pipeline

Tags: ruby, logstash

Imagine that have some logs like this

```
Jun2012|16:52:39|10.0.0.1|log|keyinst||daemon|inbound|VPN-1 & FireWall-1|Certificate initialized|
Jun2012|17:52:39|10.0.0.1|log|keyinst||daemon|inbound|VPN-1 & FireWall-1|Certificate initialized|
Jun2013|16:52:39|10.0.0.1|log|keyinst||daemon|inbound|VPN-1 & FireWall-1|Certificate initialized|
Jun2012|18:52:39|10.0.0.1|log|keyinst||daemon|inbound|VPN-1 & FireWall-1|Certificate initialized|
Jun2012|19:52:39|10.0.0.1|log|keyinst||daemon|inbound|VPN-1 & FireWall-1|Certificate initialized|
```

.....
I can see the line number in an editor but I want to calculate line number of each line and make field of it.In out put inside a json like

```
{...,"line_num" : 23, ...}
```

How can i make this ? Can someone give an example ?

Comment: Take a look at [`each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Enumerable.html#each_with_index-method) – it yields each element along with it's (zero-based) index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved that issue, with creating your own input codec plugin you can calculate line numbers via iterating over events

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has a special variable `$.` that has the line number.

```
File.foreach(logfile).each do |line|
   puts "#{$.}: #{line}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you share your logstash filter plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below with `readlines` and `with_index`

```
result = []
File.readlines('test.log').each.with_index(1) do |line, index|
  result << { content: line, line_num: index }
end
```

Output:

```
2.6.3 :042 > pp result
[{:content=>
   "Jun2012|16:52:39|10.0.0.1|log|keyinst||daemon|inbound|VPN-1 & FireWall-1|Certificate initialized|\n",
  :line_num=>1},
 {:content=>
   "Jun2012|17:52:39|10.0.0.1|log|keyinst||daemon|inbound|VPN-1 & FireWall-1|Certificate initialized|\n",
  :line_num=>2},
 {:content=>
   "Jun2013|16:52:39|10.0.0.1|log|keyinst||daemon|inbound|VPN-1 & FireWall-1|Certificate initialized|\n",
  :line_num=>3},
 {:content=>
   "Jun2012|18:52:39|10.0.0.1|log|keyinst||daemon|inbound|VPN-1 & FireWall-1|Certificate initialized|\n",
  :line_num=>4},
 {:content=>
   "Jun2012|19:52:39|10.0.0.1|log|keyinst||daemon|inbound|VPN-1 & FireWall-1|Certificate initialized|",
  :line_num=>5}]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've tried your solution in ruby plugin but that didnt work so could you share your filter plugin ?

Comment: You should be able to execute the above snippet with plain ruby and with log file

Comment: I know how to execute ruby file. If you read the question, I was asking that how can i do it in logstash pipeline. Like inside of ruby plugin. You shared just a simple loop in ruby. My question was how to implement in logstash ruby filter via using ruby filter plugin. Clearly ruby with logstash events.

Comment: Using ruby like this => 'ruby {
    code => "
      event['message'] = '...'
    "
  }'

Answer (score 0):

Logstash has no information about the line number of the event in a file, and it only tracks the byte offset when you use the `file` input.

If you are using filebeat to ship your logs to logstash you also have the information about the byte offset, but there is no tracking of the actual line number.

If you want to just order your events you can use this offset, if you need the actual line number you will need to implement a way to add this information in your event before sending it to logstash.